# How to remove specific anchor tag and following delimeter from a div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create an outlook style `To:` / recipients list when I select contacts from a javascript address book I wrote.

I have a list of contacts in an addressbook which when selected, looks like this...

```
<div class="contact selected">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="innertxt" id="c_e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">
        <span id="Test User">
        <img width="48" height="48" src="/Content/Cache/4.gif"><a href="/Management/Employee/Edit/e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206" class="contact-link">Test User</a>
        <ul>
            <li>test.user@test.com</li>
            <li>123456789</li>
        </ul>
    </span></div>
</div>
```

and a recipient div which looks like this...

```
<div id="RecipientNames"></div>
```

I have some javascript that runs to select the anchor tag within this user and add that achor to my recipient field along with a delimiter `;`

```
function ContactSelected(contact) {
    var contactLink = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a');
    contactLink.clone().appendTo("#RecipientNames");
    $("#RecipientNames").append("; ");
}
```

The contact passed into this function is the entire contact element presented at the start of this question.

Thus I end up with....

```
<div id="RecipientNames">
  <a class="contact-link" href="/Management/Employee/Edit/e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">Test User</a>; 
</div>
```

**Problem**

Given a RecipientNames div that has multiple recipients, what jquery can I use to remove the contact-link anchor tag and the following '; '.

```
<div id="RecipientNames">
  <a class="contact-link" href="/Management/Employee/Edit/e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">Test User2</a>;
  <a class="contact-link" href="/Management/Employee/Edit/e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">Test User2</a>;
  <a class="contact-link" href="/Management/Employee/Edit/e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">Test User3</a>;
</div>
```

So, for example if I wanted to remove `TesetUser2;` which is the entire `<a>` tag plus the semi-colon after. In this particular case, it is the middle user and semi-colon being removed. But they can be removed in any order so it always needs to be the semi-colon following the contact specified.

How would I go about implementing the Remove function that will be called. I have tried the following but it was a guess and consequently does not work :)

```
public ContactRemoved(contact) {
     var selector = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a').attr("href");
     var recipients = $("#RecipientNames");
     $(recipients).remove('a[href^="' + selector + '"]').remove("; ");
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
    function ContactSelected(contact)
    {
        // append selected contact name to recipient list.
        var contactLinkSpan = $("<span>");
        var contactLinkClone = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a').clone();
        contactLinkClone.appendTo(contactLinkSpan);
        contactLinkSpan.append("; ");
        contactLinkSpan.appendTo("#RecipientNames");
    }

    function ContactRemoved(contact) {
        // remove selected contact from recipient list.
        var selector = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a').attr("href");
        $("#RecipientNames").find('a[href^="' + selector + '"]').parent().remove();
    }
```

Comment: please add the smartwikify strangeness you are referring to

Comment: It was included with the original question under problem 1. I edited to re-format it onto another line to make it easier to see.

Comment: Searching around I found out that wikiflikify injection is from a chrome extension 'FasterChrome' which, as it turns out I am running. As this was the only extension I have loaded I completely forgot. I'm going to update my question to better reflect the issue I'm having with removing the anchor tag and following delimeter

Comment: thanks! Yea, I just tested out the code above in an html editor and I couldn't reproduce Problem 1

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more context around the javascript that gets executed. I have updated question. Basically I have a ContactSelected and ContactRemoved functions which the contact gets passed into when you click on them from either list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap each semicolon in a span tag (`<span id="{associated_anchor_tag}">;</span>`) and add an associative anchor tag identifier as an id attribute. When you are ready to delete a particular contact, find the appropriate span tag and perform a simple $.remove() on it

Sample code below, should help in understanding the answer above

Creating the span tag

```
var contactLink = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a');
var contactLinkIdentifier = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"]').attr("id");
contactLink.clone().appendTo("#RecipientNames");
$("#RecipientNames").append('<span id="'+contactLinkIdentifier+'">;</span>');
```

Removing the correct node

```
 function contact_removed(contact) {
     var selector = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a').attr("href");   
     var contactLinkIdentifier = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"]').attr("id");
     var recipients = $("#RecipientNames");
     $(recipients).remove('a[href^="' + selector + '"]');
     $(recipients).remove(contactLinkIdentifier);
 }
```

You can remove some lines of code if you simply add an id attribute to the anchor tag and simply call remove once

EDIT:
If you want the semicolon to be inside a `<span>` with the `<a>` tag, then simply create a new span tag and append to it the `<a>` tag clone. Some sample code below should help

```
var contactLinkSpan = $("<span>");
var contactLinkClone = $(contact).find('div[id^="c_"] a').clone();
contactLinkClone.appendTo(contactLinkSpan);
contactLinkSpan.append("; ");
contactLinkSpan.appendTo("#RecipeintNames");
```

And, when you are ready to delete, simply find the respective `<a>` tag, get its parent (which would be the `<span>` tag) and you can remove that from the DOM by calling $.remove()

Comment: Did you get a chance to test drive this answer? Would like to know if this was a suitable answer

Comment: I tried out your solution and it add's to the recipient list ok but does not remove anything. Is there a way to put the `<a>` inside the span with the `;`. This would be a little bit cleaner and then you could just remove this single span.

Comment: you can find my solution under the edit section of the answer above

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm after. I've tried this code under the edit and it runs without any javascript errors but doesn't copy anything over to #RecipientNames. Debugging it with firebug doesn't show any errors so there must be something wrong with the output not appending correctly?

Comment: This last edit of yours does achieve what I was after. I hadn't noticed at first, but you spelled the selector incorrect for #RecipientNames. I'm marking your answer as correct. Well done and thanks for taking the time to follow it through.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried putting the anchor inside the span as in my comment to @Salman. This is what I tried

`$("#RecipientNames").append('<span id="' + contactLinkIdentifier + '">'+contactLink.clone()+';</span>');`.

This however, results in [object Object] being placed inside the span. `<span id="c_e4f6ea43-03fd-4496-aa58-917a17e31206">[object Object];</span>`, rather than rendering the actual element inside the span.

I have also tried using `contactLink.clone().html()` but that just renders the html value of the element and not the entire element html.

Comment: You can't "add" DOM elements like how you did -- that will try to convert the object to a string, which is why you get "[object Object]". See @Salman Paracha's updated answer, that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and clarification. I figured that was the behaviour which was occurring.